# Wheel gestures in ubuntu?

Tags: gestures, mouse-wheel, tabs, xbindkeys

**This question is a particular case of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832411/can-i-use-complex-mouse-button-combinations-with-xbindkeys).**

Is there any program that can assign the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to the gesture <kbd>RIGHT-CLICK</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse-wheel-up/down</kbd>?

**Explanation:** I haven't managed to make this exact gesture work with neither `compiz` nor `easystroke` as they apparently only allow mouse gestures of the form <kbd>One-Mouse-Button</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>ALT</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>, and not <kbd>One-Mouse-Button</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse-Wheel</kbd>. (Maybe it's actually possible and I haven't found the right box to tick).

**Reason:** This gesture is very useful for switching through tabs in a web browser. It's possible to use it in Opera (natively), in Firefox (with `FireGestures` extension) and in Chrome (with `crxMouse` extension), but I can't get this functionality in other browsers like Tor (doesn't allow extensions).

As most web browsers use the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to switch to the next tab, it would be ideal assigning the gesture to that key combination GLOBALLY in order to use the gesture no matter the browser I'm using.

**Remark:** I'm not looking for a partial solution, but a global one. And I'm looking for the exact gesture <kbd>RIGHT-CLICK</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse-wheel-up/down</kbd>, not another one.
I'm sure there must be a way, I mean this is Linux, not iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, install `xbindkeys` and `xautomation`...

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install xbindkeys`
`sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config`
`sudo apt-get install xautomation`

Understand that configuring these **can** be difficult, but there are plenty of examples for different `.xbindkeysrc` online. Here's mine, just to get you started... you'll note that I already have a mouse wheel setup, but it's commented out, as I don't use it...

```
###########################
# xbindkeys configuration #
###########################
#
# Version: 0.1.3
#
# If you edit this, do not forget to uncomment any lines that you change.
# The pound(#) symbol may be used anywhere for comments.
#
# A list of keys is in /usr/include/X11/keysym.h and in
# /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h 
# The XK_ is not needed. 
#
# List of modifier (on my keyboard): 
#   Control, Shift, Mod1 (Alt), Mod2 (NumLock), 
#   Mod3 (CapsLock), Mod4, Mod5 (Scroll). 
#
# Another way to specifie a key is to use 'xev' and set the 
# keycode with c:nnn or the modifier with m:nnn where nnn is 
# the keycode or the state returned by xev 
#
# This file is created by xbindkey_config 
# The structure is : 
# # Remark 
# "command" 
# m:xxx + c:xxx 
# Shift+... 


#keystate_numlock = enable
#keystate_scrolllock = enable
#keystate_capslock = enable


"xbindkeys_show"
   control + shift + q

#Zoom In
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key KP_Add' 'keyup Control_L'"
b:13 + Release

#Zoom Out
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key KP_Subtract' 'keyup Control_L'"
b:10 + Release

#Tab Left
#"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown Shift_L' 'key ISO_Left_Tab' 'keyup Control_L' 'keyup Shift_L'"
#b:6 + Release

#Tab Right
#"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key ISO_Left_Tab' 'keyup Control_L'"
#b:7 + Release

#bind shift + vertical scroll to horizontal scroll events
#(xbindkey '(shift "b:4") "xte 'mouseclick 6'")
#(xbindkey '(shift "b:5") "xte 'mouseclick 7'")

#Horz scroll Left
"xte 'key KP_Right'"
b:6 + Release

#Horz scroll Right
"xte 'key KP_Left'"
b:7 + Release

#
# End of xbindkeys configuration
```

Comment: Interesting. I have no access to my computer right now, but I will investigate both programmes and try to get it working. If I get it I will mark this answer with the green tick. Thank you very much.

Comment: Added this `"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key Tab' 'keyup Control_L'"
  b:3 + b:4 + Release` to the xbindkeysrc file. Not working. I will investigate further.

Comment: I know it's tricky. Use the `xev` app to help determine the correct button numbers, etc. Use the keylists at  `/usr/include/X11/keysym.h` and in `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`  The XK_ is not needed.

Comment: The button numbers are correct. Can't find a way of telling xbindkeys that I first right-click and then wheel-up. (It works if I press both buttons at the same time)

Comment: Without having to relearn it myself, I'd recommend searching for `xbindkeys` or `.xbindkeysrc`, both here, and Google. You'll find plenty of examples that may help you.